# Wait for a callback and then using the result

Tags: python, asynchronous, callback

I'm using [Frida](https://frida.re) to run a script on a process, and I want to wait for it to send the result back to me, as a callback.

My current code looks like this:

```py
def check(target):
    global msg

    script_to_run = '''
    (omitted for brevity)
    '''
    
    # callback to handle the output of the script
    def on_message(message, data):
        global msg
        if message['type'] == 'send':
            msg = message['payload']

    session = device.attach(target.pid)
    
    script = session.create_script(script_to_run)
    script.on('message', on_message)
    script.load()
    
    # Wait for the script to send us a message
    while msg == None:
        pass

    return msg == 'true'
```

The `while` loop in particular looks a bit unoptimized, and I'm also worried about how I used that global variable... it will pollute the global scope.

**EDIT:** As it turns out, I was approaching this in the wrong direction. See my answer below for details.

Comment: At the very least, I found I should change the `pass` for a `sleep(0)`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/790246/12735366

Comment: This feels too vague to really answer.  How is `check(target)` used?  You're transforming an asynchronous function into a synchronous one, which defeats the entire point.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I realize now that messages aren’t the proper way to go about it, I should use the RPC api. I’ll elaborate both question and answer when I get home

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, as it turns out, I was approaching this problem in the wrong direction.

Instead of trying to wait on an asynchronous message, I discovered that Frida has an [RPC API](https://github.com/frida/frida-python/blob/main/examples/rpc.py).

Here's how I re-wrote my code:

```py
import frida

# --snip--

def check(target):
    session = frida.attach(target.pid)

    script = session.create_script('''
        rpc.exports = {
            check: function () {
                // --snip--
                return true;
            }
        };
    ''')
    script.load()

    return script.exports.check()
```

Much more succinct, doesn't use globals, and doesn't use a `while` loop to block.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Frida, but looking at the examples found at https://frida.re/docs/messages/ I think you should do your processing in the callback "on_message", instead of passing it to the main thread.

The Frida examples end with sys.stdin.read() which acts like a wait-forever loop. The callback is probably executing in a different thread.

So change your last lines to

```
# Wait for the script to send us a message
sys.stdin.read()
```

And change the callback to

```
def on_message(message, data):
    if message['type'] == 'send':
        print(message['payload'] == 'true')
```

Don't worry about poluting the global namespace. You are the only one using it :-)

Comment: Well, see the problem is that this function is going to be part of a larger program. So, I need to get the result back in the main thread, and block until then.